# nginx redirect with a subdomain and naked domain

Tags: nginx, redirect, ubuntu-16.04

I am attempting to figure out a redirect for my domain in my nginx config. I have these three domain names:

```
domain.com //points to server 1
www.domain.com //points to hubspot server 2, no a record to change naked domain
app.domain.com //points to server 1
```

- I need domain.com to redirect to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)
- I need app.domain.com to stay un-redirected

Everything that I am trying is redirecting ALL urls to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)!

What am I doing wrong?

One attempt, redirects everything:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    return 301 www.domain.com;
}

server {
    root var/www/domain/public;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name app.domain.com;
}
```

another attempt, redirects everything:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root var/www/domain/public;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name domain.com app.domain.com;
    return 301 www.domain.com
}
```

This one just totally breaks my config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root var/www/domain/public;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name domain.com app.domain.com;
  
    location domain.com {
      return 301 www.domain.com;
    }
}
```

---

Update:

I've updated my config to say this:

```
server {
        server_name     domain.com;
        return          301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri;

}

server {
    root /var/www/domain/public;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name app.domain.com;


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Here is what currently is happening:

- domain.com and app.domain.com both point to our google cloud server. I want app.domain.com to continue pointing here, and for domain.com to 301 redirect to hubspot
- [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) points to our hubspot server

What currently happens with the above is:

- [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) goes to the correct place (hubspot)
- app.domain.com goes to the correct place (google cloud)
- domain.com still goes to the wrong place (google cloud), but using `curl -I -L domain.com` says it is 301 redirected to the correct location! I'm so confused.

Some friends of mine testing the address for me say they are being correctly 301 redirected, but a few are not (including myself)

Here is the printout from the curl command:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 09 Aug 2020 22:33:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
Location: ht tp://www.domain.com/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 09 Aug 2020 22:33:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 54566
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 1):

`www.example.com` and `app.example.com` use the same root directory? If yes, see example below.

For `example.com` if you need redirect to www subdomain:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

For `www.example.com` and `app.example.com` without redirect and output data from `/var/www/example/public`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com app.example.com;

    root /var/www/example/public;
    index index.php index.html;
}
```

Comment: the naked domain and app.domain use the same root. I've attempted your solution and moved the redirect into its own server block but it somehow seems to have no effect at all on the site (at least, it does not redirect to www) any ideas why? Thank you!

Comment: the reason the naked domain and app.domain use the same root is because we are using hubspot for our marketing site which doesn't offer IP addresses so I can't change the a record of the naked domain and need to instead redirect it to the www subdomain

Comment: can you describe in detail what happens when you go to example.com?
are you using http or https? if you use https, in the configs that I sent it may well be that app.example.com is used earlier than example.com and you do not receive a redirect to www, because the scheme for the https was not described in configs.

Comment: I've updated the post above with my current config and the printout from testing the site using `curl -I -L domain.com`. The above is the only information that I have regarding directing to any URL on the site, so there is no HTTPS info before it, although I do have some lets encrypt stuff after it that is controlled by certbot

Comment: (www is not part of any of the server blocks because its routing is controlled via google cloud DNS and Hubspot now)

Comment: I've discovered the issue is that it's redirecting from http but not from https!